# Is it possible to convert carbon soot/ black carbon in mg to CO2-equivalent? If so, how?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, energy, carbon-family

Since global warming is expressed in terms of carbon emissions or CO2 equivalent, can the short lived carbon soot/ black carbon that is produced from incomplete combustion be expressed in terms of CO2 equivalent? I learnt Carbon soot is a major health risk. The purpose of doing this is to calculate how much of heating effect can be reduced by controlling the emissions of these carbon particles.

Answer (score 0):

Though both $\ce{CO2}$ and particulate carbon (soot) cause warming, a direct mathematical relationship of the effects would be specious for a few reasons:

- The *life-times* of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ and soot differ, and vary with amount of sunlight (enabling plants to absorb $\ce{CO2}$, but not affecting soot appreciably), with amount of precipitation (affecting both), etc.
- The heating effects differ: $\ce{CO2}$ remains in the atmosphere, [absorbing and re-emitting infrared radiation](https://scied.ucar.edu/carbon-dioxide-absorbs-and-re-emits-infrared-radiation) and thereby raising *atmospheric* temperatures more than *surface* temperatures. Soot eventually settles out, warming the *surface* more than the *atmosphere* when radiation is absorbed.
- There are other differences, such as effect of solar angle (seasonal and latitudinal variation), [albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) of the surface (e.g. is the soot falling on snow or on a dark pine forest), etc.

BTW, particulate carbon and products of incomplete combustion also have direct impact on health, such as in [burning fuels indoors](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2006/02/060215090413.htm) or [urban smog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Smog_of_London) while the physoiological impact of $\ce{CO2}$ (at current levels) is less severe.

Comment: Your insights are great. Thank you so much for sharing. I happened to read https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jgrd.50171  

13.3.2 talked about the soot to co2 equivalent conversion idea and the uncertainty that revolves around it. Can you please go through and share your thoughts?